# Java: using Jodd Jerry - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jquery, static-libraries, noclassdeffounderror, jodd

I want to use the Jodd library in java because I want to try [Jerry](http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/index.html) out.
To do that I've included the library like shown in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825521/how-do-you-use-a-java-library) and used the following code:

```
File file = new File(SystemUtil.getTempDir(), "test.html");
NetUtil.downloadFile("http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toastbrot", file);
Jerry doc = Jerry.jerry(FileUtil.readString(file));
```

Executing this code produces the following error message:

> ```
>  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
>       at jodd.lagarto.LagartoParserEngine.<clinit>(LagartoParserEngine.java:22)
>       at jodd.jerry.Jerry$JerryParser.createLagartoDOMBuilder(Jerry.java:80)
>       at jodd.jerry.Jerry$JerryParser.<init>(Jerry.java:73)
>       at jodd.jerry.Jerry.jerry(Jerry.java:121)
>       at jodd.jerry.Jerry.jerry(Jerry.java:53)
>       at sla.htmlf.Main.test(Main.java:36)
>       at sla.htmlf.Main.main(Main.java:19)
>     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
>       ... 7 more
> ```

*at sla.htmlf.Main.test(Main.java:36)
      at sla.htmlf.Main.main(Main.java:19) of course is referring to classes of my project*

This is the first time I encountered a NoClassDefFound exception. It appears that org.slf4j.LoggerFactory is missing, but if I'm not mistaken thats something the jodd library uses - which then should be included there, right?

I'd really appreciate some advice/help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the [download page](http://jodd.org/download/index.html#Maven), **jodd-lagarto** module (that **Jerry** belongs to) depends on SLF4J logging library.

Please read more about [logging in Jodd](http://jodd.org/doc/logging-jodd.html). On this page you can also find some *quick steps* to setup your environment and make it work.

These steps are:

- Go to http://www.slf4j.org/download.html and download SLF4J distribution package.
- Put **slf4j-api-X.X.X.jar** on the classpath
- If you don't want any logging, just put **slf4j-nop-X.X.X.jar** on the classpath.
- Otherwise, go to http://logback.qos.ch/download.html and download LOGback distribution package.
- Put **logback-core.jar** and **logback-classic.jar** on the classpath.

With SLF4J you can choose logging framework you want to use: none, log4j, commons etc; Jodd authors recommend [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html) library which is being referenced by one of the other libs.

Comment: The [download page](http://jodd.org/download/index.html) shows which additional dependencies are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Add `slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar` to your classpath.

Download: http://www.slf4j.org/dist/slf4j-1.7.2.zip

Answer (score 0):

[slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar](http://www.slf4j.org/dist/slf4j-1.7.2.zip) as well as [commons-logging-1.1.1.jar](http://mirror.softaculous.com/apache//commons/logging/binaries/commons-logging-1.1.1-bin.zip) was missing

Comment: Please note that commons-logging is just one option with slf4j, you can use any other logging framework as well.