# Adding a library or folder to use in my project

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, pie-chart

I am trying to add a pie chart to my project and I found this website that says it can help make it with a library or something of the sort. I am not sure what to define it as so I can't really search on how to use it.

This is the thing I want to use: http://blue-walrus.com/2012/09/simple-pie-chart-in-java-swing/

EDIT (the new link is): http://frontangle.com/icharts/#/home

I downloaded their ZIP file and then unzipped it. How am I supposed to include these files into my project? I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3 as my IDE. This will be programmed in Java.

On a side note, I have imported the Java List but I still can't use sampleList.add() for some reason? Do I need to import something else?

This is what I imported for the list: import java.util.List;

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825521/how-do-you-use-a-java-library ?

Comment: The thing is I'm a beginner and I don't even know if my file is a library or a Jar or a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Two options - 
  #1 : Either the ZIP would have a lib/bin/target folder containing some jar. This   Jar you need to include in your Project build path.

#2 : If there is a pom.xml, you need to build as in go to that directory & execute as >mvn install. This should create a target folder which would have one or more jars. Include them in your class path.

Comment: I have looked a bit into #2 and I don't know what Maven is, but I haven't used it before. Do I need Maven in order to do use the PieChart classes?

Comment: If the zip you downloaded has no jar as such, i think that is what you should do. It is good to know anyways and does not take much to have Maven on your system. Once you have built the jar using the command above, you can continue with your work (By importing the jar in your class path) without bothering about Maven.