# Using POI for excel works in Java

Tags: java, excel

I want to read/write excel files in Java (netbeans). There are a lot of information on how to do that with [APACHE POI](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) and I know that. My question is that, where should I put poi jar files? should I extract it in my local project?

Additionally, should I download the binary or src of the poi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a Java Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825521/how-do-you-use-a-java-library)

Comment: @khelwood: That is about Eclipse

Comment: Only some of the answers are about Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that Maven is the perfect choice, but if you don't have time to study about it, just try to [add the jar file to your project](https://www.foxinfotech.in/2019/03/how-to-add-external-jar-file-in-netbeans-project.html#:%7E:text=Adding%20External%20JAR%20file%20in%20NetBeans%20Project&text=In%20the%20project%20properties%20window,shown%20in%20the%20below%20image.)

Comment: OK. I downloaded poi binary package. It contains poi-3.16.jar (~2MB) and many other jar files. Is that enough to add that or I have to add all library files?

Comment: I believe that you just need one.

Comment: Although I added the jar file, but it doesn't work. I will ask in another post

Comment: I guess because the reference between the project and the library has not been made.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven you only have to add this dependency to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

With this library you can process .xls and .xlsx files.
If you are not using maven you should download the jar file and add it to your classpath

Comment: No I don't use Maven. I am developing just regular java applications. Don't know what is Maven! Please explain that

Comment: This can be usefull to understand maven http://stackoverflow.com/a/13335439/4620483

Comment: no, it is not, but it is a good practice to use such tool and it will make your life much easier